# Using Excel and VBA code is there a way to move shapes to their corresponding x, y coordinate grid?

Tags: excel, vba

I am assuming I'll need some way to convert the x, y positions to screen positions on the grid but don't know if possible. Could anyone get me started or suggest what information to look for?

Answer (score 0):

Shapes have Top and Left properties. I believe you are familiar with them. Shapes also have a property called `TopLeftCell` which returns a range object, to wit, the cell under the shape's own TOP/Left corner.

This enables you to set the shapes `TOP` property relative to the cell's Top and the shape's `Left` property relative to the cell's Left. The `TopLeftCell` property is read only but shapes are floating freely over the worksheet. So you can set the shape's `Top` equal to `Cells(14, "A").Top`, and this movement of the shape will cause its `TopLeftCell` property to change.

Moving a shape around may be undone by the shape's own properties, however. Be sure to check the box "Don't move or size with cells". Programmatically you would set the `Placement` property to `=xlFreeFloating` which has a value of 3 on my version of Excel, like `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Placement = xlFreeFloating`

Comment: I have expanded my answer to include instruction how to deal with the shape's Placement property.

Comment: Thank you, that should get me started. Appreciate your time.